# Cut with CTRL+MINUS key combination don't work

Tags: modeling

I am an intermediate with blender and I was making a 3D room
When he geets to modelling the window, he press CTRL + MINUS key to make the window's center blank, but it doesn't work for me,

I need help to solve this problem please!

Comment: Hello it's not clear what operation you are refering to, Ctrl - is supposed to select less, is it what you're talking about? Maybe share some screenshots or share the link to the tutorial you're talking about if this is the case?

Comment: Please add a link to the tutorial and specify the time in the tutorial which is causing you problems along with an image of your screen which you can do via Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu and editing it inot your question.

Comment: Have you activated the _Bool Tool_ shipped add-on? Are you in Object Mode? 
 Object-Mode Ctrl-Numpad '-' is the default keymapping for 'Subtract Sellected from Active' in that add-on.

Comment: @JohnEason No, `Ctrl`+`Numpad -` only selects less in _Edit Mode_. In _Object Mode_ with the _BoolTool_ addon enabled it is creating a _Boolean_ modifier set to _Difference_ when you have to objects selected. `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Numpad -` is the destructive workflow where the modifier gets applied immediately and the cutter object is deleted. //EDIT: Oh, you noticed it and deleted your comment :)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann That's why I deleted my comment having checcked it!